# (Python) Trying to run a command prompt command containing a variable

Tags: python, command-prompt

new to python so sorry if the question is dumb and/or obvious.
Basically, I am trying to run a command prompt command in python using os.system to open up an image. Problem is, I will be transferring both the code and the image to other people within a folder, so I want the code to work regardless of what directory the folder is placed in. I wrote some code that finds the current directory of the image and puts it in a variable, but I'm not sure how to run the command if part of it is a variable instead of one long string. Any tips, or is there an easier way to go about doing this?

```
import os

#Gets/formats directory
def getDirect():

x = list(os.getcwd())

y = ""

for c in x:
    if c == "\\":
        c = "\\\\"

for c in x:
    y = y + c

y = y + "\\imageNameHere.png"

return y

#Prints a valid directory name
print(getDirect())

#Cmd says "The directory name is invalid"
os.system('cmd /k "cd "' + getDirect())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path[[1]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-relpath-method/)

That way it does not matter where he puts his file as long as he moves the entire folder.

e.g.

Folder --> script --> script.py

Folder --> image --> image.jpeg

then the relative path is ../image/image.jpeg